# How to write a function to swap rows in a 2D array (c++)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a problem to write a functions to swap rows in a 4x6 2D matrix. The function I have currently only works for the rows in the first column. I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


void swapRows(int matrix[][6], int row1, int row2);

int main() {
    //declare variables
    int matrix[4][6], swapped, i = 0, j = 0, swap1, swap2;

    //insert random values
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    //prompt which rows to swap
    printf("Swap Row: \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &swap1);
    printf("With Row: \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &swap2);

    //swap rows
    //display swapped matrix
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            swapRows(matrix, swap1, swap2);
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//swap function
void swapRows(int matrix[][6], int row1, int row2) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            int tempRow = matrix[row1][j];
            matrix[row1][j] = matrix[row2][j];
            matrix[row2][j] = tempRow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of swapping the same rows four times repeatedly?

Comment: And then doing that four-swap-process 24 times in total? :-)

Comment: Use [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure who told you that you were learning C++, I don't think there's one *bit* of C++-specific code in there at all. This really is a C question.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio c++ application

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are swapping rows within the printing loop. But you can write the function quite simply as:

```
void swapRows(int matrix[][6], int row1, int row2) 
{
    std::swap(matrix[row1], matrix[row2]);
}
```

If you don't want to use `std::swap`, then you can swap the elements of the rows by hand, like this:

```
void swapRows(int matrix[][6], int row1, int row2) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) 
    {
        int temp = matrix[row1][j];
        matrix[row1][j] = matrix[row2][j];
        matrix[row2][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know C++11 added this overload.

Comment: Yeah, and it's constexpr from c++20 :)

Comment: My professor wants us to make a function without the built in function

Comment: @shigeru added a solution without swap.